# What is the problem in the argument?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

Consider the sequence $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$, then $\vert x_{n+1}-x_n\vert=\vert\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\vert=\frac{1}{n+1}$.
Here, $\vert x_{n+1}-x_n\vert$ can be made less that $\epsilon\; \forall\epsilon>0$ making $\langle x_n\rangle$ a Cauchy Sequence [Suppose that $\langle x_n\rangle$ is a sequence of real numbers satisfying:$\forall \epsilon>0$  there exist $n_0$ such that $\vert x_{n+1}-x_n\vert<\epsilon\;\forall n\ge n_0$] and hence convergent.

But, $x_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\implies \lim x_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty  }\frac{1}{k} $ is divergent making <$x_n$>  a divergent sequence.

So, both the above arguments are true which cannot be the case...please point out the mistake I'm making.

Comment: Well for one, the notation $x_n = \sum \frac 1 n$ is incredibly ill-defined. The summand depends on $n$? That's fine, but we need the bounds of the sum as well. I suspect you want $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1 k$.

Comment: @PrincessEev:See the edit

Comment: @Anwar: The definition of Cauchy sequence you have given is incorrect. Please consult the textbook you are studying from, or Wikipedia. A sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there are only finitely many pairs of terms $(x_n,x_m)$ such that $|x_n-x_m|\ge\varepsilon$. This definition is equivalent to the usual one given in the books.

Comment: @Anwar "*Suppose that...*" $\;-\;$ You are misquoting the definition of [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence#In_real_numbers).

Comment: The definition of a Cauchy sequence involves $|x_m-x_n|$, not $|x_{n+1}-x_n|$. That's a very important difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first argument is not correct.

A sequence $(x_n)_n$, the difference of whose consecutive terms is "eventually small", need not be convergent.

The sequence $( \sum_{k=1}^{n} 1/k )_n$ is an example. It diverges.

Comment: :But every cauchy sequence is convergent

Comment: Have you shown the sequence is Cauchy, though? The definition I'm familiar with is

$$(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists N \in \mathbb{N})(\forall n,m \ge N)(|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon)$$